# gVim status bar icon on Win10 flicker when vim-airline enabled

Tags: plugin-airline

When `vim-airline` plugin is enabled, gVim's icon on the windows status bar starts flickering as on the seen on this [screencast](https://vimeo.com/424037475).

gVim becomes slow, cursor starts flickering too.

This happens when `vim-airline` plugin is enabled. I suspect it has todo with VCS module of `vim-ariline`, as it also flickers (also seen in the screencast).

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! It looks like there's a process being spun up with each flicker: can you identify what that is? (I can see the icon coming and going in the launch bar)

Comment: Yes, I misnamed the ‘lauch bar’ as ‘status bar’. How do I check the spun process?

Comment: You could watch process/task manager or something; idk, I dont use windows much

Comment: Updated `vim-airline` git submodule in my `.vim` dir to the latest, and the issue is gone.

Comment: great! I’ve closed the question with one of our custom reasons that basically says “this is not likely to be reproducible.” Don’t take it personally; it’s just a way of indicating the question is resolved in a way that doesnt really make sense for voting/etc. Look forward to seeing your around [vi.se]!